# How to remove Main Domain cookie from Sub Domain

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

is it possible to remove  Main Domain cookie from Sub Domain ?I am using single sign on .On logout i want to remove the maindomain cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that.

But couldn't you just point the logout call at the main domain? (presumably you're already doing this for the login call, in order to get the main domain cookie in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would have to navigate to the parent domain, have *it* remove the cookie, and then maybe redirect back to the child site (perhaps passing the return url encoded on the query-string).

Answer (score 0):

not ideal and not tested / validated, but you might be able to unset the cookie on the client (e.g. using javascript). Not the most elegant solution, but could potentially work.