# Clear cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Please Is there a way to clear a particular cookie with JavaScript and it is compatible with all browsers? I am using .NET to register the script during pre_load.

Comment: Are you talking about a cookie that was set by a page on _your_ site?

Comment: Im referring to a cookie that is not set by my own site. I am trying to clear a cookie that is set by Salesforce called sid. its suppose to be the session id.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should suffice:

`<script type="text/javascript">
   function delete_cookie( name ) {
     document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
   }
</script>`

Comment: Will this be able to clear a cookie that has been set by a different site. ie. Salesforce.

Comment: For security reasons, you cannot delete the cookie of a specific domain if you aren't on that domain. This answer explains it in detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/17777005/1303004